# writing a dictionary with one key and two values to a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has one key and two values.  I want to write a dictionary to a csv file, and sorted according to one of the values.  I also want each value to have its own column in the csv file. 
I can't seem to do it.

```
sorted_combined = sorted(combined.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1][1])
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
   writer = csv.writer(output)
   writer.writerow(["Subject", "Sij", "gij"])
for key, value in sorted_combined.iteritems():
   writer.writerow(k, sorted_combined[k])
```

I know some people have said to try 
writer.writerow([k] + sorted_combined)
or 
writer.writerow(key, *value)

and neither one works. The error messages I get are: cannot concatenate tuple.

What I expect to get is the following:

```
 Subject     Sij      gij
 sub001_01   6578     18
 sub992_03   3820     5
```

*****EDIT*******
This is what my sorted_combined looks like.. however the (1,6) for instance you see at the end it not a tuple anymore it's a string.  When naming the dictionary key, each tuple was converted to a string.

[('network6_QNS_0045_01_(1, 6)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(1, 4)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(0, 6)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(2, 5)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(1, 7)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(1, 5)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(1, 3)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(5, 6)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(3, 5)', (0.0, 0.0)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(2, 6)', (743466.0, 18.387329999999999)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(5, 7)', (142774.0, 18.769649999999999)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(0, 5)', (232822.0, 20.160640000000001)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(3, 6)', (780163.0, 24.748139999999999)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(2, 3)', (199652.0, 26.635860000000001)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(4, 7)', (2248433.0, 27.278729999999999)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(3, 4)', (922289.0, 27.979320000000001)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(1, 2)', (396823.0, 29.924759999999999)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(4, 6)', (2897317.0, 30.266200000000001)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(0, 4)', (520923.0, 31.040569999999999)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(4, 5)', (6358.0, 32.68)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(2, 4)', (3622715.0, 35.321170000000002)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(2, 7)', (364815.0, 37.499250000000004)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(0, 1)', (145240.0, 38.878059999999998)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(0, 7)', (224456.0, 46.5182)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(0, 3)', (1692.0, 56.884950000000003)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(6, 7)', (280955.0, 57.616190000000003)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(3, 7)', (2012.0, 71.302719999999994)), ('network6_QNS_0045_01_(0, 2)', (1660.0, 84.085009999999997))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my answer, you are not using a dictionary. You have a list of tuples.

```
import csv 
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Subject', 'Sij', 'gij'])
    for row in sorted_combined:
        l = [row[0]]
        l.append(row[0][1])
        l.append(row[1][1])
        writer.writerow(l)
```

Just like you had in your original try, csv.writer is the way to go

Comment: I keep getting this error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"
at this line of code:
  f.write(', '.join([str(x) for x in sorted_combined[key]]))

Comment: I notice I get this error everytime i put in square brackets around key

Comment: can you print what your values in the sorted_combined dictionary look like

Comment: Also I was just wondering, would it still be a tuple even though I changed it to string format in the dictionary? @alexshchep

Comment: I just edited my answer. You are not using a dictionary, so you have positional indices instead of keys

Comment: To make it tab separated, just change commas to `\t`, as suggested by Batuhan

Comment: There's only one issue now,"network6_QNS_0045_01_(1,6)" has been separated into "network6_QNS_0045_01_(1" into one column and "6" in the other column. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: ah yes, csv.writer is the way to go to avoid this, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list, flatten it and simply write it using [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). I don't know if there is a shorter way, though.

```
import csv

my_dict = {"sub001_01": [6578,18], "sub992_03": [3820,5]}

with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    w=csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(["Subject", "Sij", "gij"])
    for i in list(my_dict.items()):
        #We first make a list like: ['test', 1, 2, 3]
        list1=[a for a in i]
        list_final=[]
        list_final.append(i[0])
        for c in list1[1]:
            list_final.append(c)
        #We use writerow() to write our new list
        w.writerow(list_final)
```

**Output:**

```
Subject,Sij,gij
sub001_01,6578,18
sub992_03,3820,5
```

To use '\t' instead of commas, **just specify the delimiter**

```
w=csv.writer(f,delimiter="\t")
```

Which will produce:

```
Subject Sij gij
sub001_01   6578    18
sub992_03   3820    5
```

P.S: This is for Python 3.X

Edit: Forgot to mention that this is a universal loop that can handle more than 2 values. You can use it with other dictionaries (with lists containing multiple values) as well.

Comment: thanks, I was just wondering how I could get it in the format I showed above.  In a table, with each value having it's own column instead of being separated by commas.

Comment: Very easy :) Just add delimiter="\t" to csv.writer() || w=csv.writer(f,delimiter="\t")